# Chamfer tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

Does ArcGIS Pro have [chamfer tool](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-97D6FA66-3A0D-4F16-9D6F-092220F76C99) like that of AutoCAD or not because my project allow to use chamfer only?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [fillet tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/create-a-fillet-between-two-segments.htm) that creates curved edges, but exploring the AutoCAD help the chamfer tool creates bevelled edges.

In ArcGIS Pro, using the basic rectangle tool and then constraining direction/angle to create a right-angle triangle I used the clip tool to clip out the corners to create the bevelled edge as shown below, this was admittedly a bit fiddly but quite achievable.  You need only spend some quality time reading the help file.

[image: Polygon]

Having created the polygon I simply created a [preset-template](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/create-a-preset-template.htm) from the selected feature and now I can create hundreds of polygons with the specific bevelled effect.

[image: Many polygons]